# PySpark null values imputed using median and mean being able to handle non numeric columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, imputation, pyspark

I have created the following code which works like I want when all the columns are numeric data types, its input arguments are the original dataframe and method of imputation I want for the dataframe depending on which I specify and its output is the dataframe with imputed data:

```
def Imputation(df, method):
    if method == 'median':
        imputer =  Imputer(inputCols=df.columns, outputCols=["{}_imputed".format(c) for c in df.columns])
        Median_Imputer = imputer.setStrategy("median").fit(df).transform(df)
        cols = [c for c in Median_Imputer.columns if c.lower()[-7:] == 'imputed']
        Median_Imputer = Median_Imputer[cols]
        return Median_Imputer
    elif method == 'mean':
        imputer = Imputer(inputCols=df.columns, outputCols=["{}_imputed".format(c) for c in df.columns])
        Mean_Imputer = imputer.setStrategy("mean").fit(df).transform(df)
        cols = [c for c in Mean_Imputer.columns if c.lower()[-7:] == 'imputed']
        Mean_Imputer = Mean_Imputer[cols]
        return Mean_Imputer
    else:
        return None
```

However, this code breaks down whenever any of my columns are non-numeric. For non numeric columns, I want to impute the value "missing" for every null value.

The following code I created can fill in null values with "missing" for all columns:

```
df.select([(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), "missing").otherwise(df[c])).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

however it does it for all columns numeric and string type. How can I incorporate the last line of code with my above function so that I can cover both cases, imputing using either median/mean for numeric columns as well as filling out "missing" for all string columns? The imputer function seems to impute for all columns at once so I am not quiet sure how to iterate (or do it in another way) to incorporate both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both Imputer and your method takes all DataFrame's column, but if your input for Imputer are numerical columns, and for your method are categorical columns, then the problem solved

The question comes down to how did you access the numerical/categorical(string type) column.

```
str_dtype_list = list(filter(lambda tup: tup[1]=='string', df.dtypes))
str_col_list = [x[0] for x in str_dtype_list]
```

This give you list of column name that is string type, you can do this for int/double as well.

Then when you use `Imputer(input_col=num_col_list)` and `df.select([(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), "missing").otherwise(df[c])).alias(c) for c in str_col_list]+num_col_list + str_col_list).show()`

Both of the code will keep all the old column, plus the Imputed column